# Add UITapRecognizerController to UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have an `imageview` which I had added a `tapRecognizer` to like this:

```
recognizer1 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap1)];

UIImageView *crossImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((jrect.origin.x+jrect.size.width), (jrect.origin.y-20), 30, 30)];
crossImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross.png"];
[crossImage addGestureRecognizer:recognizer1];
[self addSubview:crossImage];
```

`handleTap` method:

```
- (void)handlePan1:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"FV");
}
```

When I click the image nothing happens. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3):

```
crossImage.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

You need enable user iteraction. By default is NO for UIImageView.